# How to programmatically close external application?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application, I used to start through  `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` external application for viewing images/videos and so on.

For security reasons I need to close started Intent from my application. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which application you're launching use

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

You can get the process id from the running process using this class: [RunningAppProcessInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html)

You can't get that directly, because that is a violation of security:

Why don't you limit the choices given to the user by calling [setPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29)

If you really want to know which application was launched, here is the code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
    getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

Comment: How would I know application PID? I'm launching it through Intent which presents user selection which one to start. How would I know user's selection?